# What is the time complexity of this algorithmic problem?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, big-o

*
A search method has time complexity O(n2), where n is the number of states in the space to be
searched. If it takes 1 second to search a space of a thousand states, roughly how long will it take to
search a space of a million states?*

I have found that its approximately 12 days but the way I found  is quite wrong i think. 
I did 1million^2 / 86400(seconds in a day ) and found 11.56 so approximately 12 days. Is there a better and more efficient solution?

Comment: This question should be asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) I think.

Answer (score 1):

There is not nearly enough information to answer this question.  See [Big-O description](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html).

**O(N^2)** means only that the algorithm's execution time will be dominated by an N^2 term.  As N grows large, the ratio between two execution times will asymptotically approach the square of their ratios.  It says nothing about the execution time for particular values.

Let's keep this simple, assuming a set-up overhead with an array initialization **O(N)** and some system start-up, a constant.  This makes the execution time

```
t = a * N^2 + b * N + c
```

for some values of a, b, and c.  Even if we know that this is the equation form, we do not have enough information to solve given only one (`t`, `N`) data point.  We don't know enough to derive `t` for `N= 10^6`.

---

I suspect that whomever posed this problem is looking for the *invalid* solution, making the unwarranted assumption that N=1000 has already blown all smaller terms to insignificance.  In this case, simply scale up by the square of the size ratio:

```
N1 / N2 = 10^6 / 10^3 = 10^3
Scale up by N^2, or (10^3)^2 = 10^6
```

That gives you 10^6 seconds, or somewhat over a day; I'll leave the math to you.